# Understanding Crash log for iOS iPad, iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

I am facing a problem with reading crash logs in iOS. I updated the app then sent it to App store. Now I am getting crash reports. I want to fix these crashes but I couldn't read the log.

Where is the actual error message?

Here is the log:

```
    Incident Identifier: B2A90B2D-931C-49CC-B357-21372248E0BC
    CrashReporter Key:   634bf464908ebe6c51ac2ffd13270a80859ccf34
    Hardware Model:      xxx
    Process:             DronaWithStoryBoard [1023]
    Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8FB555CC-32AE-465B-B1AB-AF3F5E31CAF4/DronaWithStoryBoard.app/DronaWithStoryBoard
    Identifier:          com.deltecs.DronaLite
    Version:             3.0.0 (6.0.0)
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]

    Date/Time:           2015-10-30 13:47:12.12 -0700
    Launch Time:         2015-10-30 13:47:12.12 -0700
    OS Version:          iOS 9.1 (13B143)
    Report Version:      105

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Filtered syslog:
    None found

    Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
    6148914687.966154 CFNetwork                     0x0000000185235928 TCP Conn 0x14f762cc0 starting SSL negotiation
    6148914687.966585 CFNetwork                     0x0000000185235928 TCP Conn 0x14f648d80 starting SSL negotiation
    6148914687.966619 CFNetwork                     0x00000001852d7a30 TCP Conn 0x14f762cc0 complete. fd: 13, err: 0
    6148914687.967027 CFNetwork                     0x00000001852d7a30 TCP Conn 0x14f648d80 complete. fd: 7, err: 0
    6148914687.968015 CFNetwork                     0x00000001852d8f5c TCP Conn 0x14f762cc0 event 1. err: 0
    6148914687.968440 CFNetwork                     0x00000001852d8f5c TCP Conn 0x14f648d80 event 1. err: 0
    6148914688.053584 CFNetwork                     0x00000001852d9034 TCP Conn 0x14f762cc0 started
    6148914688.053584 CFNetwork                     0x00000001852d9034 TCP Conn 0x14f648d80 started
    6148914688.055810 CFNetwork                     0x000000018532e608 Creating default cookie storage with default identifier
    6148914688.055810 CFNetwork                     0x000000018532e5d4 Faulting in CFHTTPCookieStorage singleton
    6148914688.055843 CFNetwork                     0x0000000185380394 Faulting in NSHTTPCookieStorage singleton



    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000185de4620 0x185d88000 + 378400
    1   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000185d9c194 0x185d88000 + 82324
    2   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000185d9af28 0x185d88000 + 77608
    3   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000185d96d34 0x185d88000 + 60724
    4   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000185d94bd0 0x185d88000 + 52176
    5   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x0000000186101670 0x1860f8000 + 38512
    6   libRIP.A.dylib                  0x0000000186100a7c 0x1860f8000 + 35452
    7   CoreGraphics                    0x0000000185e2d08c 0x185d88000 + 675980
    8   QuartzCore                      0x000000018a90e0a8 0x18a8b4000 + 368808
    9   QuartzCore                      0x000000018a90d710 0x18a8b4000 + 366352
    10  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a90e6fc 0x18a8b4000 + 370428
    11  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a90d724 0x18a8b4000 + 366372
    12  DronaWithStoryBoard             0x0000000100181618 0x10009c000 + 939544
    13  DronaWithStoryBoard             0x0000000100181d2c 0x10009c000 + 941356
    14  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a8db4d8 0x18a8b4000 + 160984
    15  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a8bd944 0x18a8b4000 + 39236
    16  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a8bd630 0x18a8b4000 + 38448
    17  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a8bccc0 0x18a8b4000 + 36032
    18  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a8bca08 0x18a8b4000 + 35336
    19  QuartzCore                      0x000000018a8b60f8 0x18a8b4000 + 8440
    20  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185aebbd0 0x185a10000 + 900048
    21  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185ae9974 0x185a10000 + 891252
    22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185a18cc0 0x185a10000 + 36032
    23  UIKit                           0x000000018b1361c8 0x18b0b0000 + 549320
    24  UIKit                           0x000000018b130ffc 0x18b0b0000 + 528380
    25  DronaWithStoryBoard             0x00000001000ac224 0x10009c000 + 66084
    26  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019b1ca8b8 0x19b1c8000 + 10424
```

Comment: First of you should [symbolicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports) the crash log only then can you tell where arises. The `EXC_CRASH` is an abnormal termination of your app. `0x0000000000000000` tell you it is a `NULL` pointer problem some where.

Answer (score 0):

use crashlytics framework provided by twitter and supported by apple.... which will automatically generate detailed crash logs with exact problem at exact location in code. Best of luck

Comment: already doing it, but this came on app review and not caught by crashlytics. :(

Comment: this error occurs due to access memory out of bound or memory which not exist... please check your responses from web services... are they correct?